# como verificar a internet antes de abrir um app ionic?

Tags: android, ionic, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um *app ionic* com um *iframe*. Até o momento o *app* está completo e rodando, mas quando acesso o mesmo sem internet aparece uma mensagem de erro.

Gostaria de colocar uma mensagem ou uma tela para que caso tenha internet acesse a página onde tem o *iframe*, caso não tenha internet mostre uma mensagem.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Comment: IONIC 1 ou 2?...

Answer (score 1):

Caso seja **IONIC 2**, veja aqui na própria [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) sobre `Network` no qual você precisa usar o método `onDisconnect()` para verificar se possui ou não conexão.

De acordo com a documentação, basicamente é preciso importar a *lib*:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
```

Abaixo segue como você pode usar o método `onDisconnect`

```
let connection = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {

   // mensagem no console que não possui conexão.
   console.log('Não possui conexão com internet :-(');

  // aqui você insere o layout/iframe/mensagem para exibir para o
  // usuário informando que não possuir conexão com internet
});
```

Comment: Não deveria ser no `onConnect()`?

Comment: @ramaral na verdade dá quase mesma coisa. Se tiver desconectado é porque não está conectado! haha

Comment: Não sei, não conheço o ionic. No entanto, normalmente para haver `onDisconected` é necessário ter havido uma conexão bem sucedida. Caso a conexão não tenha sido conseguida não haverá onDisconected.

Comment: sim, mais tenho que criar um service ou posso colocar no home.ts, pois o iframe carrega no home.html e queria mostrar uma mensagem ao inves do erro, caso nao tenha conexao